# using findAssocs in R to find frequently occurred words with central term

Tags: r, correlation, tm

As I was working with findAssocs in R, I realised that the function don't actually pick up the words that occur together with the searched term **across** documents, but rather the words that occur when searched term frequently appeared.

I've tried using a simple test script below:

```
test <- list("housekeeping bath towel housekeeping room","housekeeping dirty","housekeeping very dirty","housekeeping super dirty")
test <-Corpus(VectorSource(test))
test_dtm<-DocumentTermMatrix(test)
test_dtms<-removeSparseTerms(test_dtm,0.99)

findAssocs(test_dtms,"housekeeping",corlimit = 0.1)
```

And the returning result from R is:

```
$housekeeping
 bath  room towel 
    1     1     1
```

Noticed that the word "dirty" occur in 3 out of the 4 documents, compared to the returned keywords which only occurred once in all documents.

Anyone has any idea what went wrong in my script or if there is a better way to do this?

The result I want to achieve is the model should reflect the words that occurs frequently with the search term across all documents and not within a specific document. I've tried combining the 4 documents into 1 but it doesn't work as findAssocs doesn't work on a single document.

Any advise?

Comment: Check out the result of `cor(c(2,1,1,1), c(0,1,1,1))`.  That's your correlation calculation for "housekeeping" with "dirty".  It's -1, and `findAssocs` requires correlations to be between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Jota Appreciate that you highlighted that, could you advise if there's alternative to this if the word that I want to highlight here is "dirty"?

Comment: Yes, you could dig into the code for `findAssocs` and modify to your needs.  For example, here's something I dug out of the code and didn't test at all: `j <- match("housekeeping", Terms(test_dtms), nomatch = 0L);  slam::crossapply_simple_triplet_matrix(test_dtms[, j], test_dtms[, -j], cor)` or you could look at other packages.  `quanteda` has a `similiarity` function you can check out.  It supports a good number of similarity & distance measures that you can look into.

Comment: @Jota Thanks for recommending the quanteda package! It seems to have a very comprehensive text mining solution within the package. I find this post very helpful to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357656/tm-package-findassocs-vs-cosine. i tried using the author's method on cosine similarity and achieved the desired results. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about an alternative, using the **quanteda** package?  It imposes no mystery restrictions on the correlations returned, and has many other options (see `?similarity`).

```
require(quanteda)

testDfm <- dfm(unlist(test), verbose = FALSE)
## Document-feature matrix of: 4 documents, 7 features.
## 4 x 7 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
##        features
## docs    housekeeping bath towel room dirty very super
##   text1            2    1     1    1     0    0     0
##   text2            1    0     0    0     1    0     0
##   text3            1    0     0    0     1    1     0
##   text4            1    0     0    0     1    0     1

similarity(testDfm, "housekeeping", margin = "features")
## similarity Matrix:
## $housekeeping
##   bath   towel    room    very   super   dirty 
## 1.0000  1.0000  1.0000 -0.3333 -0.3333 -1.0000
```

Comment: Thanks. It does seems much clearer on its correlation of -1 which Jota mentioned. Nonetheless, isn't showing a correlation of -1 a bad proof to business users? I've tried using the cosine method and it does seems to solve the issue from the test example. But when i tried it on my larger dataset, the words that are supposed to show becomes less important again due to the searched terms appearing more times in a particular document.

Comment: I'm wondering then, if it is possible to cut the searched term to 1 for every documents so that all documents only have 1 searched term tagged to them and all have an equal chance to get spotted? But is this considered as "manipulating the data"?